# Meaning of $x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}$ (multi-index notation)

Tags: notation, definition, index-notation

I'm attempting to understand Wikipedia's [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space#Definition) of the Schwarz Space, in particular, the sentence

$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\left|x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}\right|<\infty.$$

Given $\alpha, \beta\in \mathbb{N}^n$ I understand the meaning of the notations $x^{\beta}$ and $D^{\alpha}=\partial ^{\alpha}$ individually, but I do not undestand the meaning of
$$x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}.$$

What is its meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you what
$$
\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\left|x^{\beta}D^{\alpha}f(x)\right|<\infty.
$$
means.  Start with a function $f$.  Take a certain partial derivative of it.  Multiply by a monomial in $x$.  Absolute value of the result.  Take the supremum of that over all $x$.
Example
$$
x^{(2,4)}D^{(3,7)}f(x) = x_1^2 x_2^4 \frac{\partial^3}{\partial x_1^3}\frac{\partial^7}{\partial x_2^7}f(x_1,x_2)
$$